# AWS load balancer that pass through self sign certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an instance that runs nodejs express in a private subnet using self sign certificate.
I wish to put it under a loader balancer that will forward the clients connected to it with the original certificate to the instance.
I tried the above with ssl proxy policy using an elb and it doesn't work. The instance still receives the wrong certificate.

Is there code changes I need to perform on the express side?

Comment: You will have to upload your certificate to aws and than change your ELB to check this certificate and allow th inbound connection in your security group.

Answer (score 0):

I did that but I use a self sign certificate that it's validated on my nodejs app. So when the nodejs middleware receives the load balancer connection it rejects it because it receives the LB SSL.
I tried using ELB instead of ALB and added proxy policy but still it does work. I need a way to make the LB pass the client pem to the instace.